# End an operation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a rather funny question, but I am new to C#. So plz help. In my program there is a main form with a button. When I click on this button another form appears. This subform has a "back" button and a "save" button. When I click "save" is saves the data and opens a browser so that I can choose a file. When I click "back" it should just close the subform. My problem is I can't make it "STOP" there. After it closes the subform (and despite using "return") it just continues to go to the method written in the main form which is for opening the browser and goes on until another "if" is false. How can I make it stop there? (BTW, the reason that the open browser method is written in the main form is that there are several subforms that need to be open from the main form, all with the same style). 
Editing: 
in the subform (GuaranteesForm)I have

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("No Data was saved");
            return;
        }`
```

Then it goes to main form:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GuaranteesForm frm = new    GuaranteesForm(Convert.ToInt32(txtProjectReferenceCode.Text),
                    txtIndent.Text, 7, "");
                frm.ShowDialog();
                lblId.Text = _entit.C02_ProjectDocuments.OrderByDescending(i => i.ID).First().ID.ToString();
                UploadFirst();
                lblId.Text = "";
                RefreshData();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }

        }
```

Then the method for the First load:

```
  private void UploadFirst()
    {

            OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog { Multiselect = true };
            opf.ShowDialog();


            if ((opf.FileNames.Any()))
            {
                tempDictionary.Clear();

                foreach (var fileName in opf.FileNames)
                {
                    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
                    lstFile.Items.Add(f.Name);
                    tempDictionary.Add(f.FullName, f.Name);
                }
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("File Was NOT saved !");
                return;
            }
```

If I press back it opens the browser then I close the browser and it show :File was NOT saved

Comment: in a subform set `DialogResult` and in main form check if you get back a valid `DialogResult` before proceeding

Comment: You have to provide your code let's see how you open and close the subform. Let's see your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ShowDialog` method suspends the current method until that dialog is closed, and then continues the suspended method. The `return` statement in the `btnBack_Click` method **has no effect** on the main form - you'd need to tell the main form what the user had decided. This can be done using the `DialogResult` property.

*Instead* of using `this.Close()` in the dialog, use `DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel`:

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Data was saved");
    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; // this also closes the dialog
}
```

In the event handler of the button that *should* cause the file to be saved, use `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` instead of `Close()`:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // this also closes the dialog
}
```

Then in the main form, you can then act on the user's decision:

```
if (frm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
{
    // bail out
    return;
}

// continue showing the browser and saving the file
```

---

PS. `Button` has a `DialogResult` property, which automatically sets the dialog result and closes the form when it has a value other than `DialogResult.None`, without the need for a `Click` event handler.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you thank you thank you. You're a life-saver!

Answer (score 0):

You should call the uploadfirst() method from your subform in the "save" button event handler. Remove it from the "button8" eventhandler